# get the results of the "run after" in Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a step UpdateJobListingFromSilkroad that runs Azure Function.
the next step is email to myself to know if it failed.
I set the "run after" to all 4 options.
In the email body I want to get the results of the "run after"
so I found the result function.
When enter result() I can't save because "The template language function 'result' must have at least one parameter."
So I tried result(UpdateJobListingFromSilkroad) it tells me it is invalid so is result("UpdateJobListingFromSilkroad")
but result('UpdateJobListingFromSilkroad') is valid but saving shows error:

```
at line '1 and column '345' references the action 'UpdateJobListingFromSilkroad' 
of type 'Function': 
only the actions of type
'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Templates.Schema.FlowTemplateOperationType,System.String]' are allowed to be referenced by 'result' function. '.
```

So how do I get the results?

Comment: So much overhead for something so simple

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your operation UpdateJobListingFromSilkroad inside Scope. Then take a result of the scope.
Please find more details here http://johnliu.net/blog/2018/9/the-curious-tale-of-the-result-function-in-flow-logicapps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29997392)